# SQL Query construct

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have three tables. I want to get data from all those tables and put it in a virtual table. i am using SQL Server 2012. 
Sorry if my format or tags are wrong because I m getting error `Stack overflow requires external javascrip from another source domain, which is blocked of failed to load.`

**Booking Table**

```
BookingId   |   date
======================
2           |   7/1/2017 (MM/dd/yyyy)
3           |   7/1/2017
```

**BookingCost Table**

```
Id  |   bookinId | Cost
==========================
1   |   2        | 2000
2   |   3        | 4000
```

**Expense Table**

```
Id  |   ExpenseCost | Date
======================
1   |   1400        | 7/2/2017 (MM/dd/yyyy)
2   |   1422        | 7/1/2017
3   |   4000        | 6/3/2017
```

I want to get Monthly result like following Table.

```
Date        | Expense  | Bookings
===================================
jan/2017    |   0      |    0
feb/2017    |   0      |    0
    .       |   .      |    .
    .       |   .      |    .
    .       |   .      |    .
jun/2017    |   4000   |    0
jul/2017    |   2822   |    6000    
    .       |   .      |    .
    .       |   .      |    .
    .       |   .      |    .
```

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  What is the relationship between the three tables?

Comment: BookingId is primary key in booking table. And foreign key in booking cost table... Expense table is independent

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have only date to access both bookings and expenses.

Comment: I think you need to tell us how `Expense` relates to the other tables.

Comment: Expense is independent.. Not related to any table.. I m getting expenses between specific date range.  Its just little extra spices on food ... Not realy any major role in software.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is something like this (assuming your dates are DATE types and not VARCHAR - otherwise you could convert them).

```
SELECT COALESCE(EXPENSE.MONTH, BOOKINGS.MONTH) [Date], EXPENSE.Cost Expense, BOOKINGS.Cost Bookings
FROM (
  SELECT DATEADD(DD,1-DAY([date]),[date]) MONTH, SUM(Cost) Cost
  FROM Booking
  INNER JOIN BookingCost
    ON Booking.BookingID = BookingCost.BookingID
  GROUP BY DATEADD(DD,1-DAY([date]),[date])
) BOOKINGS
FULL JOIN (
  SELECT DATEADD(DD,1-DAY([date]),[date]) MONTH, SUM(ExpenseCost) Cost
  FROM Expense
  GROUP BY DATEADD(DD,1-DAY([date]),[date])
) EXPENSE
  ON EXPENSE.MONTH = BOOKINGS.MONTH
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: My dates are date type.. I just wanna show them as month and year.. And wanna sum all the amount of month and show it as single record.. .. M testing ur query.. Plz wait

Comment: your answer is doing work but not properly..  First add **)** at end of line 12.. 2nd query is returning data day wise.. I need one row for whole month.. 3rd query is showing wrong date against data.. For example i have **bookingCost** of 39956 saved against date 6/20/2017 but query is showing date 6/15/2017 ... Also i have 2 entries of expense against date 25... Query is summing them up and showing against date 20...  Means 5 days subtracting.

Comment: Very sorry, don't know what I was thinking. I've fixed the missing bracket and corrected the date to month. It returns 1st of Month which you can then convert to required format in various ways.

Comment: Thanks bro.. It worked like a charm... But one thing... Swap names from line 8 and 13. You are placing expenses in booking column and vice versa. Everything else is working great.. Thanks bro...

Answer (score 0):

To also get the 0 counts, you could left join the totals to a tally table which has all the months for the year.

The sql is using [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) to transform the Date

For example:

```
;WITH MONTHS AS
(
  select 
  [Year], [Month], 
  format(datefromparts([Year],[Month],1),'MMM/yyyy') as [MonthYear]
  from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) m([Month])
  cross join (values (2017)) y([Year])
)
select 
 m.[MonthYear] as [Date], 
 coalesce(e.TotalExpense,0) as Expense,
 coalesce(bc.TotalCost,0) as Bookings
from MONTHS m
left join (
 select 
  datepart(year,[Date]) as [Year],
  datepart(month,[Date]) as [Month],
  sum(ExpenseCost) as TotalExpense
 from Expense
 where datepart(year,[Date]) in (select distinct [Year] from MONTHS)
 group by datepart(year,[Date]), datepart(month,[Date])
)e on (e.[Year] = m.[Year] and e.[Month] = m.[Month])
left join (
   select 
    datepart(year,b.[date]) as [Year],
    datepart(month,b.[date]) as [Month],
    sum(c.Cost) as TotalCost
   from Booking b
   join BookingCost c on c.BookingId = b.BookingId
   where datepart(year,b.[date]) in (select distinct [Year] from MONTHS)
   group by datepart(year,b.[date]), datepart(month,b.[date])
) bc 
on (bc.[Year] = m.[Year] and bc.[Month] = m.[Month])
order by m.[Year], m.[Month];
```

---

Test data I used

```
declare @Booking table (BookingId int, [date] date);
insert into @Booking (BookingId,[date]) values (2,'2017-07-01'),(3,'2017-07-01');
declare @BookingCost table (Id int, BookingId int, Cost int);
insert into @BookingCost (Id, BookingId, Cost) values (1,2,2000),(2,3,4000);
declare @Expense table (Id int, ExpenseCost int, [Date] date);
insert into @Expense (Id, ExpenseCost, [Date]) values
(1,1400,'2017-07-02'),(2,1422,'2017-07-01'),(3,4000,'2017-06-03');
```